# Reload data on worksheet change

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Excel workbook with two worksheet (sheet1 and sheet2). I've some cell of sheet1 referenced from sheet2. 
I've done this using formula like this...

```
=sheet1!C2
```

This should change the derived cells of sheet2 if I change values in sheet1. but unfortunately it's working at first load but not after that.. how can i refresh the derived cells using macro

Comment: by default it should update automatically. are there any macros running? set `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to Sheet1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim col As Range

    For Each col In Sheet2.UsedRange
        col.Calculate
    Next
End Sub
```

Every time you make a change on sheet1, sheet2 will recalculate which should update the value of formulas.